# Can't find Plist file in my Dev environment

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I tried saving a Plist from my project and using NSLog printed out the path of the file.
I was using the iOS Simulator 4.2.
But I can't find it anywhere on my Mac.

> /Users/Wayne/Library/Application Support/iPhone
>   Simulator/4.2/Applications/0C42C550-530A-4F2C-A422-6D948F2166A3/Documents/Message.plist

Any ideas where it could be?

Comment: Have you run 'Reset Content and Settings' since you logged that path?  It may not exist anymore.

Comment: Can you describe in more detail? You get to that path and the file is gone? On lion that path is hidden. Have you tried while the app is running? Can you post the code where you write out the file?

Comment: @jackslash I checked out the path in Terminal (any way to unhide it? Using Terminal to copy it seems pretty lame) and found the file - thanks. I tested with an array and this code `[speedArray writeToFile:plistPath atomically: TRUE];` Now I don't know how to write out my array of Class instances...

Comment: @jackslash You should "Answer" my question instead of just a comment so I can check it and credit you properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The path your plist is being stored is

```
/Users/Wayne/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.2/Applications/0C42C550-530A-4F2C-A422-6D948F2166A3/Documents/Message.plist
```

On OS X 10.7 Lion this path is hidden by default. There are several ways you can access this path.

1) Go to terminal and type

```
open "/Users/Wayne/Library/Application\ Support/iPhone\ Simulator/"
```

This will open the Finder at the iPhone simulator main directory.

2) In Finder click the "Go" menu and then hold the "option" (sometimes called "alt") key. The option to go to your User library will appear. Then you can navigate to the iPhone Simulator Directory.

3) If all of this seems a bit much and you would rather your ~/Library folder was visible all the time then you can go into terminal and unhide it using the following command

```
chflags nohidden ~/Library
```